# Debugging a NextJS/React application in Storybook through WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, storybook, javascript-debugger

I have a NextJS app I'm working on developing. I'm currently trying out [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) to develop the various components in isolation of each other.

If I run the app via `npm run dev` then WebStorm will perfectly stop at my breakpoints, but if I run the app in Storybook via `npm run storybook` (a script for `storybook dev -p 6006`) I can do seemingly nothing to get it to stop at breakpoints.

I've tried attaching to an already running browser, installing Chrome to replace Firefox as the WebStorm debugger [only supports Chromium-based browsers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-debugger.html). I've checked I don't use webpack or any source map problem (debugging the app normally works anyway).

Is it even possible to attach a debugger to Storybook, or am I approaching this problem from completely the wrong angle?

In the meantime I'm going to debug my components out of isolation as part of the full app, but any pointers on getting the WebStorm debugger to attach to Storybook or troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.